# Network adapter state [Wireless]

Tags: networking, wifi, adapter

What does a wireless network adapter "disassociated state" mean?

Please help.

I cannot seem to find an explanation anywhere.

T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that even though you can see a Wireless network SSID being broadcast on the client interface's spectrum/wireless range, you are not talking to it directly.  Once you associate (meaning: choose to talk to this network), then the next step would be to authenticate if there is the need to do that via security measures implemented by the network administrator.

[**https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5418**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5418).  Check out the "Forming an association (joining)" part for a more technical overview of this phase of the connection process.